# Extract data from one Azure SQL DB, transform and load into another Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

We have two Azure PaaS SQL Servers, one in our production resource group and another in our QA resource group.

I'm looking for the best way to 'copy' the data from an Azure SQL DB in the production resource group to an Azure SQL DB in the QA resource group. As part of this process the data must undergo some simple transformations to anonymise the data before it lands in the QA DB.

We have deletion locks in place on the resource groups so deleting and recreating databases is an option I'd rather avoid.

The 'copying' can take place on a weekly schedule and it would be acceptable to drop any existing data in the target Azure SQL DB each time the process is run.

What are the most suitable options in Azure to accomplish this?

Comment: How did you want to deal with the data?  Please try Data Factory Data Flow, it have many functions and support expression,  it can help you achieve that.

Comment: Hi @TonE, do you have any other concerns? Please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with Azure Data Factory.  You can use it for pretty much anything that SSIS was used for onsite, and more.